# What will be displayed in the next node.js code sequence , if requestResource is an asynchronous method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What will be displayed in the next node.js code sequence , if requestResource is an asynchronous  method?

```
let resource = requestResource(success, fail)
console.warn(resource)
```

Comment: Without seeing the code for `requestResource()` it's impossible to say; it could be literally anything. The fact that it's asynchronous suggests that it *might* return a Promise.

Comment: Most likely `f requestResource(success, fail) {//..code}`

Comment: if the requestResource method need too much time for its execution, then the console result will be 'undefined'.

Comment: You need to show the code for `requestResource()` because if it obtains `resource` asynchronously, then it CANNOT return the value directly and `resource` will always be `undefined`.  Your function will return BEFORE the async operation is done.  If the function really takes two callbacks, then the asynchronously obtained result is probably passed to the `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some promise for requestResource() to give it something, it will only show undefined.